# How to approach a "select any option"

Tags: jquery, select

I have this select in my html code:

```
<select id="select_type">

</select>
```

I need to put a "option" in my select so in my jquery froman aray:

```
array.push('a');
array.push('b');
array.push('c');
array.push('d');
for (var i in array) {
    console.log("hi");
    $('#select_type').append('<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + array[i] + '</option>');
}
```

The problem is that I can see the option that I create in for also if I read the "hi" print. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over array, use `for`

Comment: Please see [ask] and **[mcve]**. Use [edit] link and update the post accordingly.

Comment: @Tushar Can you help me in the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Wrap inside `document`'s `ready` function. (I believe the script has loaded before the DOM loads)
2. Initialize the `array`.

```js
$(function () {
  var array = [];
  array.push('a');
  array.push('b');
  array.push('c');
  array.push('d');
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log("hi");
    $('#select_type').append('<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + array[i] + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_type">
</select>
```

Also, please don't use `for...in` for iterating arrays.

Also, I don't understand the reason behind your `.push()` for individual elements. That can be refactored using:

```
array.push('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Finally, using `.append()` or any DOM Modifications inside a loop is costly. So you might consider the better code this way:

```js
$(function () {
  var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  var finalHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log("hi");
    finalHTML += '<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + array[i] + '</option>';
  }
  $('#select_type').append(finalHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_type">
</select>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is that bad?

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect See the [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description). Quoting here _Objects created from builtin constructors like Array and Object have inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and String.prototype, such as String's indexOf() method/Object's toString() method. The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override prototypesproperties)._

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect That would iterate on the properties as well, like `length`, etc.

Comment: I don't get the point in `push`ing each element in array individually, when they can be added at the time of instantiation. Also, instead of going to DOM each time in `for` is slow, any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `forEach` loop

```js
var array = [];
array.push('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

array.forEach(function(el) {
  $('#select_type').append('<option value="' + el + '">' + el + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_type"></select>
```

You could also use JQuery `$.each` loop, and you can add all options to one string inside loop end then append that string to `HTML` as @Tushar suggested

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], string = '';

$.each(array, function(i, el) {
  string += '<option value="' + el + '">' + el + '</option>';
});

$('#select_type').append(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_type"></select>
```

Comment: Why not initialising array with elements? Also, adding new element in DOM inside `forEach` is costly, any other way where you've to jump in DOM only once?